# Запуск скрипта python после подключения к wi-fi LINUX

Tags: python, linux, сеть

Есть задача запустить скрипт python требующий интернета после включения компьютера.
Подключение осуществляется через wi-fi, но происходит только спустя секунд 30 после запуска все системы. 
Пробовал через rc.local скрипт запускается перед инициализацией wlan0 и крашится.

Подскажите, какие есть еще варианты запуска скрипта после соединения с интернетом?

Comment: Варианты: вставить нужный фрагмент скрипта в цикл с перехватом исключений. Или просто сделать в начале скрипта паузу в минуту, а потом уже все выполнять.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри в сторону [Cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), должно помочь

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт лучше запускать через сервис и указать в зависимости `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`

/etc/systemd/system/python.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Python Server
After=NetworkManager-wait-online.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /opt/script_dir/script.py
WorkingDirectory=/opt/script_dir/


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

systemctl enable python.service

Или посмотри на диспечер сети. Добавь файл `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/python-iface-events.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

interface=$1
event=$2

if [[ $interface != "eth0" ]] || [[ $event != "up" ]]
then
  return 0
fi

/usr/bin/python3 /opt/script_dir/script.py
```